# FOS Elastica -- getting string representation of query

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony-2.3, foselasticabundle

I am unit-testing a repository that uses FOS Elastica and I was wondering if anyone knows how to get the string version of a query, rather than in array form. Here is my repository method:

```
    /**
     * Creates query object by either first or last name, with given parameters
     *
     * @param $name
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return Query
     */
    public function findByFirstOrLast($name, array $params)
    {
        $queryString = new QueryString();
        $queryString->setQuery($name);
        $queryString->setFields(array('firstName', 'lastName'));


        $query = new Query();
        $query->setQuery($queryString);
        $query->setSort(array($params['sort'] => array('order' => $params['direction'])));

        return $query;
    }
```

Assuming `$name = 'foo';` (and that I am sorting on id), I believe the corresponding FOS Elastica query should be

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "query_string":
            {
                "query":
                    "foo",
                    "fields":["firstName","lastName"]
            }
    },
    "sort":
    {
      "id":
          {
              "order":"asc"
          }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get this json-string representation of the query? It doesn't necessarily have to be in this pretty format either, it can be a one-line string.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this right? Trying to figure out the same thing at the moment.

Comment: Nope, sorry. We ended up not using FOS Elastica because it doesn't handle creating (or populating, updating, etc) indices with mappings between more than one entity very well. Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see you no longer are using this but I ended up needing the same thing.

Right before return $query you can use json_encode($query->getQuery()->toArray()) and that should give you what you need as a single line string.

Comment: To make it a bit easier to copy-paste into the ElasticSearch 'head' plugin, do: print json_encode(array('query' => $query->getQuery()))."\n";

Comment: Seems we must use $query->getQuery()->toArray() now as getQuery can return a Query object.

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/commit/da852653c484f87e19ca10c8255eb68847bbde2d

Comment: but in this kind of query the types will be missing so it is NOT the exact representation of the executed query:-(

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question but very related. When using a tool like [found.no](https://www.found.no/play) to test your elasticsearch queries, it can be interesting to have the output as YAML so you can paste in the found.no editor like this:

```
query:
    filtered:
    query:
        multi_match:
            query: php
            operator: AND
            fields:
                - field1^30
                - field2
                - field3                    
                - _all
```

You can have this kind of output with the following function:

```php
use Elastica\Query;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;

/**
 * @param Query $query
 * @param bool  $asYaml
 */
protected function debugQuery(Query $query, $asYaml = false)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    $debug = ['query' => $query->getQuery()->toArray()];

    if (false === $asYaml) {
        echo json_encode($debug, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        die();
    }

    $dumper = new Dumper();
    $yaml = $dumper->dump($debug, 100);

    echo $yaml;
    die();
}
```

So you can choose either format.